# Parse JSON file on C++ and take all subfilelds of main key

Tags: c++, json, boost

I use boost library and need to parse some json file on C++.

For ex. json (part of it):

```
{
    "media": {
        "Test1": "https://storage.tst",
        "Test2": "https://storage.tst"
    }

}
```

I want in the cycle (possible I will have many strings like test (test2, test4...))
fill some dynamic array with two levels- names (test) and address field (key value). I want to take each field of "media" and put this field in to this 2-level dynamic array.
And I want to make it with C++11 or older methods.

Comment: Whatever JSON parsing library you're using it will definitely have, as part of its API, a way to enumerate the JSON structure, like that. Which part of your JSON library's API is unclear to you, specifically?

Comment: On SO, it's customary to include the code you have so we can see where you are stuck/don't have to make up context that might not match what you're actually working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `boost::json` you could parse:

```
json::value sample = json::parse(R"(
    {
        "media": {
            "Test1": "https://storage.tst",
            "Test2": "https://storage.tst"
        }

    })");
```

Now you can iterate the properties like:

```
for (auto& [k, v] : sample.at("media").as_object()) {
    std::cout << k << " -> " << v << "\n";
}
```

To put it in a "two level array" (that doesn't exist), I'd expect you mean something like: [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ac3cb9a90c21c78)

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> not_an_array;
for (auto& [k, v] : sample.at("media").as_object()) {
    not_an_array.emplace(k, v.as_string());
}

fmt::print("not_an_array: {}\n", not_an_array);
```

Prints

```
not_an_array: {"Test1": "https://storage.tst", "Test2": "https://storage.tst"}
```

---

Documentation used: [`value`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/dom/value.html), [`at`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__value/at.html), [`object`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__object.html) and [`as_string`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__value/as_string.html)

Comment: should I init k, v like a string? First.

Comment: because compiller has an error at undefibed "k" and "v"

Comment: That's not "init" but "declare". I'm guessing your compiler doesn't support C++17 yet, I'd use this instead http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8736e9e9aeb911e0 If you really want to manually declare `k` and `v` you would need to have something like: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/E65TdMooT

Comment: Yes, sure, declare. No, I want to use old style compiller C++11 for example.
And with your approach I had next error here:
for (auto& kvp : sample.at("media").as_object()) {
identificator sample is undefined